# Why Yii2 user->save () makes redirect?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a user model extends AciveRecord implements IdentityInterface. I should check user with OpenId and if it exist i will duplicate user entry in my db. All works, but i have a problem.

After creating user i want to assign rights for him but when i call user->save() page redirect at user/login.

Behaviors:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['rbac','users','logout', 'index', 'whoami', 'user-change-data-handler','login', 'openid', 'showoid', 'openid-signup', ''],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'openid', 'showoid', 'openid-signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'showoid', 'whoami', 'user-change-data-handler', 'showoid'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['users',],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['UsersAdministrator'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['rbac',],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['RBACAdministrator'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        // 'verbs' => [
        //     'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        //     'actions' => [
        //         'logout' => ['post'],
        //     ],
        // ],
    ];
}
```

After entering a login user redirects to

```
public function actionOpenid()
{
  if (empty($_GET['username']))
      return $this->render('openid');
  $client = new OpenId();
  $client->authUrl = 'http://*******/openidserver/'.$_GET['username']; // Setup provider endpoint
  $client->setReturnUrl('http://127.0.0.1/backend/web/site/showoid');
  $client->setUserAttributes('user/email');
  $url = $client->buildAuthUrl(); // Get authentication URL
  return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url); // Redirect to authentication URL
}
```

And OpenID redirects to

```
public function actionShowoid()
{
    $client = new OpenId();
    if (!$client->validate()){
        $this->redirect(Url::to('site/login'));
    }
    else  { // validate response
        $strings=explode('&', $_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]);
        $openid = [];
        foreach ($strings as $k => $v) {
            if (!preg_match('/.+=.+/', $v))
                continue;
            $vals=[explode('.',explode('=',$v)[0])[1], explode('=',$v)[1]];
            $openid[$vals[0]] = $vals[1];
        }
        $openid['username'] = explode('%2F',$openid["identity"]);
        $openid['username'] = $openid['username'][count($openid['username'])-1];
        $user = \common\models\User::findOne(['username' => $openid['username']]);
        if ($user ==null){
            $user = new \common\models\User;
            $user->username = $openid['username'];
            $user->password_hash = 'Debugging';
            $user->save();
//------------all below ignores
            if (1){
                    $id = $user->id;
                    $assignment = 'AccessAdministrator';
                    $url = Url::to(['api/add-assignments', 'user_id' => $id, 'item_name' =>$assignment, 'apiKey'=>$this->apiKey]);
                    file_get_contents($url);
                }


            $user->save();
            \Yii::$app->user->login($user);
            $this->redirect(['site/index']);

        }
        else{
            \Yii::$app->user->login($user);
            $this->redirect(['site/index']);
        }
    //var_dump(\common\models\User::findOne(['username' => $openid['username']]));
    }
}
```

Comment: why       if (1){   ?   .. before rights assign ?  what mean?

Comment: There was a real condition and i chage it with 1 to be shured that 'if' block works.

Comment: Maybe you have got method `save()` in `User` overridden (with redirect)? Or some behavior is attached that does it.

Comment: Check this first. Nothing. Project written by myself, there is no someone's code that i miss.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the  if(1) and eventually do this way

```
    .....
    $user->password_hash = 'Debugging';

    if ($user->save()){
           var_dum('just for test');
            $id = $user->id;
            $assignment = 'AccessAdministrator';
            $api->assignRole([$id,$assignment])

        }
```

and remember that when the code end .. you should render  or redirect to some page  otherwise could be redirected  to default destination  page eg: site/login

Comment: Nope. Still redirects.

Comment: where it redirects ?

Comment: Are you sure that the assign save the data ??   Update your question and show all your controller code please .. could be that the assign don't save data and at the end of your code you have a redirect?

Comment: Redirect to site/login

Comment: Absolutelly shure. I look at this table, user was correctly saved.

Comment: @Teo    not the user saved  but the rights assign  saved ... explain better .. you have a redirect to site/login at the end of the action?  yes or not ? .. if you show all the controller code  is more  easy

Comment: User saved. Not rights. Code execution stop after user->save(). User saves correctly and then page redirect to site/login.

Comment: All controller have no sence, i think

Comment: I have update the answer with a brief suggestion .. let me know